# Angular 5 material datepicker not working with moment date adapter and target es2015

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular5, angular-material-5, angular2-moment

After switching from target es5 to es2015 (es6), the datepicker is not working anymore when deploying with --prod flag. I also tried adding `--aot` flag, but it didn't change anything. The outcome looks as follows:

[image: datepicker blank instead of showing dates]

Following Error is thrown:

[image]

Using NativeDateAdapter instead of MomentDateAdapter is no solution, as it's necessary that the datepicker is localized correctly.

Only reference i found is:

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10347

But as it turns out, there is still no solution.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now by conducting a shift from

```
angular 5.2.3 -> angular 7.1.4
```

and therefore the angular/material also changed

```
angular/material 5.2.4 -> angular/material 7.2.0
```

and together with es2015 it is working great now.

So I can't exactly say what was causing the issue but with newer versions of angular and angular/material it is resolved.